# regular expression to catch specific phrase

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to catch a text saying below words using 'regular expression' in python and would like to substitute it with 2 X 3 contingency tables

> 2><3 contingency    tables

Here's the code I've been using which sadly didn't work properly.

```
pattern = re.findall(r'[0-9]\>\<[0-9]', giRaw)
print(pattern)
re.sub(r[0-9]\>\<[0-9], r'[0-9]X[0-9]', giRaw)
```

It would be nice if you can teach me how to correct the code.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: If `2` is a placeholder for any single digit, `3` is a placeholder for one or more digits and `"contingency tables"` is a literal that must be matched I believe you can use `re.sub` with [this](https://regex101.com/r/KD3w2Z/1/) regular expression.

Comment: If the aim is to replace `><` with `X`, as @CarySwoveland suggested, we can use `re.sub`. `re.sub(r"><", " X ", giRaw)`